# Differentiate weightx and ipadx in GridBagConstraints (Java)

Tags: java

I am confuse of what is the difference between weightx and ipadx in GridBagConstraints. For what I observed, both changes the cell's width size.

Base on documentation.

> weightx

Specifies how to distribute extra horizontal space.

> ipadx

This field specifies the internal padding of the component, how much space to add to the minimum width of the component.

For me both have the same results in cell's width size. So can someone explain the effect of this in the layout or the effect of it when you resize the frame or panel? and when to use weightx rather than ipadx? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> For me both have the same results in cell's width size.

It should be very apparent what the difference is.

1. The ipadx is a fixed amount added to the width. So it will affect the width of the component when the frame is packed.
2. The weightx controls how much the column will grow/shrink as the width of the panel containing the component changes. So you will only notice the effect once the frame is visible and you resize the frame.

If you don't see the difference then your code is not implemented correctly. Maybe your layout managers don't allow the panel to grow dynamically and therefore the component can't grow either.

The basic strucuture of your code would be:

```
JTextField textField = new JTextField(20);

GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
//gbc.ipadx = 100;
//gbc.weightx = 1.0f;

JPanel content = new JPanel( new GridBagLayout() );
content.add(textField, gbc);

frame.setContentPane( content );
```

If you still have problems then post a proper [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) that demonstrates the behaviour. That is create a frame with a single component. Do a test with just the ipadx, then the weightx and finally with both constraints and you will see the difference.

Comment: Thanks I got it now ^.^ . This is the first time I used GridBagLayout and I usually use "gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH" that is why I don't really see the difference of the two but I got it now. But what is the other value for weightx? I tried 2.0f but I its the same.

Comment: @Techreator, I clarified my answer. The weightx is used to determine how much space is allocated to the column. If you then use fill, the component will expand to fill the space available in the column. When you use different weightx values for different components it determines how much space goes to each column. So, for example if you use 1.0 and 2.0, then the second column will get twice the space of the first column.

Comment: Now its getting complicated. -_-

Comment: @Techreator, what is the reason for unaccepting the answer?

Comment: Oh. I double click it maybe. sarreh ^.^ Thanks by the way. :))))